# Error in JSP (/index1.jsp (line: [16]) According to TLD or attribute directive in tag file, attribute [items] does not accept any expressions)

Tags: jsp, jstl

Can someone please help in resolving below issue.

I am trying to understand using the variable tag in c:foreach element in jsp file, so i took below example code, but somehow its not working for me.

I have put index1.jsp in WebContent folder and EmptyTagWithAttrsExport.java in Java Resources/src/com/java2s folder; and dis.tld in WebContent/WEB-INF/tld folder.
While running, i am getting error:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/jstl4] threw exception [/index1.jsp (line: [16], column: [6]) According to TLD or attribute directive in tag file, attribute [items] does not accept any expressions] with root cause
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /index1.jsp (line: [16], column: [6]) According to TLD or attribute directive in tag file, attribute [items] does not accept any expressions
```

index1.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
// start comcat and load the following jsp page in browser
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.sample.com/dist" prefix="java2s" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

<html>
  <head>
    <title>A custom tag: scripting variable</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    output:

    <java2s:defineObjects howMany="5" name="numbers" />
    <ul>
      <c:forEach items="${numbers}" var="currentNumber">
        <li>
          <c:out value="${currentNumber}" />
        </li>
      </c:forEach>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

EmptyTagWithAttrsExport.java

```
package com.java2s;


import javax.servlet.jsp.*;
import javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.*;

public class EmptyTagWithAttrsExport extends TagSupport {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5986013033799724428L;
    // Code to implement the "howMany" attribute
      private int howMany;
      public int getHowMany()
      {
        return howMany;
      }
      public void setHowMany(int i)
      {
        howMany = i;
      }

      // Code to implement the "name" attribute
      private String exportedArrayName;
      public String getName()
      {
        return exportedArrayName;
      }
      public void setName(String s)
      {
        exportedArrayName = s;
      }
      
      public int doStartTag() throws JspException
      {
        int[] outputArray = new int[howMany];
        System.out.println("Generating " + howMany + " numbers");

        for ( int i=0; i<howMany; i++ )
        {
          outputArray[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
        } // end of for ()
        
        
        pageContext.setAttribute(exportedArrayName, outputArray);

        return SKIP_BODY;
      }

      /*  public int doEndTag() throws JspException
      {
        return super.doEndTag();
      }*/
}
```

dis.tld

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>

<taglib version="2.0"
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-jsptaglibrary_2_0.xsd">

    <tlib-version>1.2</tlib-version>
    <short-name>dist</short-name>
    <uri>http://www.sample.com/dist</uri>

  <!-- this tag lists random numbers; the HTML is hard-coded within
       the tag handler
    -->
 
  <!-- this tag exports random numbers in a named array -->
  <tag>
    <name>defineObjects</name>
    <tag-class>com.java2s.EmptyTagWithAttrsExport</tag-class>
    <body-content>empty</body-content>
    
    <variable>
      <name-from-attribute>name</name-from-attribute>
      <variable-class>int []</variable-class>
      <declare>true</declare>
      <scope>AT_END</scope>
      
    </variable>

    
    <attribute>
      <name>howMany</name>
    </attribute>
    <attribute>
      <name>name</name>
    </attribute>
  </tag>

</taglib>
```

Answer (score 0):

The jstl core lib path is wrong, after using below, it worked fine
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>